# Giving a CMS page a PHP variable

Tags: php, cms

Hi guys I'd like to be able to give my CMS pages a PHP variable so that I can identify them and display a PHP array on the page (Basically giving me great control over the content that is displayed within my CMS pages).

***Is this possible?***

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use CMS page Identifiers , and identify them using

```
Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
```

and fetch the code according to that

Or Code the page in a PHTML file and call that into your CMS page that way u will have more flexibility